# How can I calculate time difference between 2 different rows for the same user

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

There is usually an in and out time for each employee when they enter and exit a room, can be messed up sometimes as people forget to swipe and tailgate another employee. I would like to calculate the time spent in the room.

the report shows:

1. user1 in    door    time
2. user1    out   door    time
3. user2    in    door    time
4. user2    out   door    time
5. etc.

```
SELECT 
    u.userid 
    ,u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName] AS EmployeeName
    ,et.name AS [Description]
    ,MAX(e.LoggedTime) AS SwipeTime
    ,d.name AS door
FROM [Users] AS u
LEFT JOIN [Events] AS e ON e.RecordIndex1=u.UserID
LEFT JOIN [EventTypes] AS et on e.EventTypeID = et.EventTypeID
join [Doors] AS d ON e.RecordIndex2 = d.DoorID
WHERE LoggedTime > CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())  and d.doorid in ( 32, 50, 42, 51, 33) 
GROUP BY 
    u.userid,u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName]
    ,et.name
    ,d.name
ORDER BY 
    u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName]
    ,MAX(e.LoggedTime)
```

I would like the report to show:

1. user1 in    door    time
2. user1    out   door    time
3. user2    in    door    time
4. user2    out   door    time

with a column added after time column with a calculation with the difference in time between users in and out time

Comment: What is the issue you are facing and where is your sample data? You have your query, so what is wrong with the output?

Comment: If the data is anything like data for our door system, this will end up being a gaps and islands problem.

Comment: @dfundako I am looking for a way to add a calculated column with the time differences/user. eg. user1  in door1 10:00, user1 out door2 10:05. user1 was in that room for  5 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for operations between rows, the LAG function is the goto solution.

[LAG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
LAG (scalar_expression [,offset] [,default])  
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )
```

You can  use this to refer to a preceding (or following using LEAD) row

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed